# Pr0blem with KivyMD / Проблема с KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How do I pass an id variable from a kv file to the rest of the code? he doesn't see her. For example this code: How to make sure that there is no error and everything is printed? I already asked this question in Russian and Spanish stackoverflow, but no one answered me

```
KV = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'button'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.4}
        on_press: app.func()
    MDTextField:
        id: text
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def func():
        print(text.text)
Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `func()` to:

```
def func(self):
    print(self.root.ids.text.text)
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).